# How to perform AS/400 login validation from Java program running on WebSphere server?

Tags: java, authentication, ibm-midrange

I am trying to create a Java program hosted on WebSphere server which can validate AS/400 login information. The user profile and password would be entered by user via a Java web front end application and passed to the new program. This program would then attempt to validate the login information on the connected AS/400, for instance, password correctness, user profile existence, etc, and pass the result back to the front end. Is it possible to perform such validation in Java? Any special packages required? The AS/400 database access is controlled by another profile and no need to be validated here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jt400 package to access the AS/400 resources.

jt400 is available from http://jt400.sourceforge.net/, and if you use maven 7.10 is unofficially available from Maven Central  (see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dk.kewill.thirdpartymavencentral/jt400-full/7.10)

Note that each incorrect login attempt for typically configured AS/400 systems will count down towards a disablement, making it trivially easy to disable any account, so you will most likely need an existing account to connect to the system and then investigate the account you are curious about.  (I have not actually tried the latter, but the API's are there).

Note:  You can develop this remotely (where you will need the jt400.jar) but when deployed WebSphere makes jt400 available on the classpath.

Comment: I have realised that my company has already acquired the IBM AS400 related Java classes so I can directly use AS400.java to verify the login information.

Comment: Normally jt400.jar is preinstalled on the system (with native optimizations) somewhere under ...ProdData... You can refer directly to that in your classpath.